# How do I use hover to hide many divs?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use :hover for four different divs that appear in a row on a website developed in wordpress.

If I hover the first div it shows the child DIV but the other three are visible through it for some reason, but if I hover the last one they all disappear. I have tried using visibility: hidden; and that didn't work.

I then have a corresponding CSS code for #reviewhover 2, 3 and 4.

Is there any way for me to do this with out using Javascript?

```css
 .reviewwrapper
    {
 color: white;
 width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
 background-color: #209dad;
    }

    .reviewwrapper:hover  #reviewhover1 {
    display: block;
    }


    .reviewwrapper #reviewhover1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #209dad;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width:70em;
    height:20em;
    margin-top: -10em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
    margin-left: -35em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
    }
```

```html
 <div class="reviewwrapper">
    text
    <div id="reviewhover1">
    text
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviewwrapper">
    text
    <div id="reviewhover2">
    text
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviewwrapper">
    text
    <div id="reviewhover3">
    text
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="reviewwrapper">
    text
    <div id="reviewhover4">
    text
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I had added a class to the text to center it inside the DIV which I removed from the question because it said I have too much code. The problem is if I add class or ID to the text it stays visible, if I remove it disappears when I hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I was vertically aligning the text.

---

I was using

```
#reviewtext {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
top: 50%;
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

---

I changed it to

```
#reviewtext {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
/* more style: */
height: 14em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have reviewWrapper1, reviewWrapper2... then you can add the hover.

Comment: I tried that. It gives me the same outcome.

When I hover reviewwrapper1 then 2, 3, 4 are still visible, but if I hover reviewwrapper4 1, 2, 3 disappear.

Comment: Try to have just one class for reviewhover.

Here's the code I made.

http://jsfiddle.net/t2av6wgb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector:

```
.reviewwrapper:hover [id^="reviewhover"] {
  display: block;
}

.reviewwrapper [id^="reviewhover"] {
   ...
}
```

---

## Explaination

You can use attributes to select elements for CSS, in the following format:

```
[attribute="value"]
```

You can also use specific selectors before the `=` to specify if the value of the attribute should start, contain or end with the value supplied. In this case we've used `^` to specify it should **start with** the following value. [Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

```
[attribute^="value"]
```

In this way, we are able to apply styles to all elements with an `id` that begins with `reviewhover`, therefore matching all of the requested elements (`reviewhover1`, `reviewhover2`, `reviewhover3`).

> **Warning** it will also match any over variation, such as `reviewhover-somethingelse` so you must be careful not to clash.

---

## Demo

I have added some background colours to the `reviewhover` elements so it is clear which is appearing.

```css
.reviewwrapper {
  color: white;
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #209dad;
}

.reviewwrapper:hover [id^="reviewhover"] {
  display: block;
}

.reviewwrapper [id^="reviewhover"] {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #209dad;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70em;
  height: 20em;
  margin-top: -10em;
  /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
  margin-left: -35em;
  /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
}

.reviewwrapper:hover #reviewhover1 {
  display: block;
}

.reviewwrapper #reviewhover1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviewwrapper">
  text
  <div id="reviewhover1">
    text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="reviewwrapper">
  text
  <div id="reviewhover2" style="background: red;">
    text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="reviewwrapper">
  text
  <div id="reviewhover3" style="background: blue;">
    text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="reviewwrapper">
  text
  <div id="reviewhover4" style="background: pink;">
    text
  </div>
</div>
```